# setDefaultCloseOperation() in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

Is there a way to set a custom closeoperation in JavaFX. I know this one from swing and couldn't find it for JavaFX. If you close your window here by pressing the [X], it will close automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `onCloseRequest` property:

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
        System.out.println("CLOSING");
    }
});
```

Note that if you call `Platform.exit()` in your code, this won't work.